# How to filter on report?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I am working on a report in AX 2009. I want to filter data of InventSiteID on the basis of ExpDate.

I have 2 datasource in the query which is attached to report. Both the data source are same InventExpired. I have to show 4 fields in dialog i.e. SiteID, Exp Date for datasource1 and same for datasource 2 and then filter it out.

Answer (score 1):

In your report, you can use

```
SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(this.queryRun().query().dataSourceNo(1),
                            fieldNum(InventExpired, ExpDate)
                           ).value(SysQuery::value(yourFilterDate));
```

That will filter the first datasource with the date entered.
If you need to filter by dates greater than or less than the filter date, you can use

```
SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(...).value('>' + SysQuery::value(yourFilterDate));
```

or

```
SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(...).value('<' + SysQuery::value(yourFilterDate));
```

Do you know how to add the fields to the dialog?

If you don't, you should override the dialog() method, and in the dialog() method, after the call to super(), you should use:

```
Dialog d = ret;
expDateField = d.addField(typeid(yourDateEDT), "Expiry Date");
```

To get the values from the fields and use them in your report, you should use

```
expDateField.value()
```

I haven't tested this, but I've done similar things on numerous occasions so I'm fairly confident this will work.  Let me know if you have any problems with this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify a range here is how I accomplished it.  Hope this helps somebody...

### Method1:

```
 qbds3 = qry.dataSourceTable(tableNum(DMxVehicleTable));
 SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldNum(DMxVehicleTable,VehicleMSRPRetails)).value(strFmt('(VehicleMSRPRetails >= %1) && (VehicleMSRPRetails <= %2)', queryValue(VehicleMinPrice), queryValue(VehicleMaxPrice)));
```

### Method2:

```
qbds4 = qry.dataSourceTable(tableNum(DMxSysYearTable));
SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds4, fieldNum(DMxSysYearTable,Year), 1, 1).value('>' + SysQuery::value(VehicleModelYearStart));
qbds4.addRange(fieldNum(DMxSysYearTable, Year)).value(strFmt('< %1', queryValue(VehicleModelYearEnd)));
```